# Unify a generic type variable to another existing type

Tags: type-inference, elm

There's a [line](https://github.com/evancz/elm-architecture-tutorial/blob/bbe9e3f76a2415734349583f562465e45c1c6f46/examples/05-time.elm#L33) from [Elm guide](https://guide.elm-lang.org/effects/time.html) below:

```
Task.perform AdjustTimeZone Time.here
```

I've found the following type signatures:

```
-- ∵
AdjustTimeZone :  Zone -> Msg
here           :                  Task x     Zone
perform        : (a    -> msg) -> Task Never a    -> Cmd msg 
-- ∴
perform AdjustTimeZone here :                        Cmd Msg
```

How could `Task x Zone` be unified to `Task Never a`? Especially, `x` to `Never` is doubtful while `Zone` to `a` reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

I'm no type inference expert, but I don't think it's correct to say that "`x` unifies to `Never`" and suspect this is the source of your confusion. `x` and `a` are both type variables which will unify either way unless there are other constraints that come into conflict. So just as `a` becomes `Zone`, `x` becomes `Never`, not the other way around.

You might also wonder why `Time.here` has the type `Task x Zone` rather than `Task Never Zone` since, after all, it's `here` that should know whether or not it can error. I *think* this is because 1) it doesn't matter (to the type system, though it certainly might for the user), and 2) it makes it more easily composable.

So let's say you want to sequence `Time.here` with some other `Task` that *can* error. `Task.andThen` has the type `(a -> Task x b) -> Task x a -> Task x b` with the `x` (error) type variable being the same in all `Task`s. So if `Time.here`s type was `Task Never Zone`, we'd have to supply `andThen` with a function `Zone -> Task Never b`. And that obvosuly won't work.

I'm pretty sure you could just do `TasK.here |> Task.mapError never |> Task.andThen (\zone -> ...)`, but this isn't really necessary if the error type is left a type variable rather than be constrained to `Never`. And that isn't a problem since `Task.here` won't produce any `x`s, so it doesn't matter what it unifies as.